# How to add item to chosen student from list and get an empty list in class?

Tags: python, list, function, class

I need to create two functions in python to class "sClass" - first one that adds a grade to concrete student from list and second one that clears students_register and returns an empty list (only names without grades). There´s no problem with adding grades to chosen student to first Class, unfortunatelly, I need to create both functions in the second class. Any idea how to do it?

```
class Student(list):
    def __init__(self, name, grades=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.extend(grades)
    def __str__(self):
        grades = ""
        for i in self:
            grades += str(i) + ", "
        return self.name + ": " + grades
    def say_name(self):
        return self.name
    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if int(grade) in range (1,6):
            self.append(grade)
        else:
            print ("Add correct grade!")


class sClass(list):
    def __init__(self, students_register=[]):
        self.extend(students_register)
    def __str__(self):
        result = ""
        for student in self:
            result += str(student) + '\n'
        return result
    def add_student(self,student):
        if student not in self:
            self.append(student)
    #def add_grade_to_chosen_student(self, name, grade):
        #self.extend
    #def clear_students_grades(self):
        #def __init__(self, students_register=[]):
            #self.remove()
    def Student_name(self, student):
        return Student.say_name()


George = Student("George", [1,2,3])
John = Student("John", [1,1,5,5,5])
Emily = Student("Emily", [1,2])
A_class = sClass([George, John, Emily])
print(A_class)
Emily.add_grade(4)
print (A_class)
```

Comment: @DJanssens Many thanks for your comment! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I'll give it an attempt.

I believe you just want to pass the student object as parameter to the `add_grade_to_chosen_student` method (in your `sClass`).

Inside that method you want to call the method `add_grade`on the student object, like

```
def add_grade_to_chosen_student(self, student, grade):
    student.add_gade(grade)
```

for your clear_students_grades function you will have to iterate over sClass's self and clear the grades of the students. This can be accomplished by writing a `reset_grades` method in the student class. The code in `clear_students_grades` in sClass will look something like:

```
def clear_students_grades(self):
      for student in self:
           student.reset_grades()
```

I have to say that I'm not a fan of inheriting of the list class for a student object. It's confusing. It might be better to use composition here instead of inheriting ( you let a student object hold a list object that represent its grades.). Also take a look at @John Zwinck's comment.

Comment: You're right that having Student inherit from list is confusing!  A student is no more a list of grades than a list of friends, favorite foods, siblings, or dream jobs.  This isn't just your personal opinion, it's a pretty standard practice to avoid inheritance when it isn't a true "X is a Y" relationship.